# Cannot find module using Yarn v. 3

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I am following this installation guide and got error cannot find module - https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install

Here is repo - https://github.com/worldpwn/yarn-3-cannot-find-module-error

### Step 1 Install Corepack

```
$ node -v
v16.13.0
$ corepack enable
```

### Step 2 Initializing your project

```
$ yarn -v
1.22.15

$ yarn set version stable
➤ YN0000: Retrieving https://repo.yarnpkg.com/3.1.1/packages/yarnpkg-cli/bin/yarn.js
➤ YN0000: Saving the new release in .yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs
➤ YN0000: Done in 0s 508ms

$ yarn -v
3.1.1

$ yarn init -2
{
  name: 'yarn-3-cannot-find-module-error',
  packageManager: 'yarn@3.1.1'
}
```

### Step 3 Install Lodash

```
$ yarn add lodash
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed 
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0013: │ lodash@npm:4.17.21 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0000: └ Completed
➤ YN0000: Done in 0s 165ms
```

### Step 4 Run hello world

index.js

```js
console.log('hello world')
```

```
$ node index.js
hello world
```

### Step 5 Use lodash - ERROR

index.js

```js
var multiply = require('lodash/multiply');
console.log(multiply(3, 5))
```

```
$ node index.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'lodash/multiply'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\a.kniazev\Documents\GitHub\yarn-3-cannot-find-module-error\index.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\a.kniazev\Documents\GitHub\yarn-3-cannot-find-module-error\index.js:1:16)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\a.kniazev\\Documents\\GitHub\\yarn-3-cannot-find-module-error\\index.js'←[39m
  ]
}
```

P.S. npm is working fine in other projects

If i will do npm i:

```
$ npm i

added 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 934ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Everything works:

```
$ node index.js
15
```

Answer (score 2):

I figure out that the problem is that I have to run index.js using this command:

```
$ yarn node index.js
15
```

As I understand it uses PnP to resolve dependencies:

https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp

https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp#initializing-pnp

Answer (score 0):

Building on Andrei's answer (this is from https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp#initializing-pnp):

> As a quick tip, all `yarn node` typically does is set the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable to use the `--require` option from Node, associated with the path of the `.pnp.cjs` file. You can easily apply this operation yourself if you prefer:
>
> ```
> node -r ./.pnp.cjs ./server.js
> NODE_OPTIONS="--require $(pwd)/.pnp.cjs" node ./server.js
> ```